# RDOMail.Delete 2 throws MAPI_E_UNKNOW FLAG with outlook 2007

Tags: outlook-redemption

The title says it all,

I have an issue with redemption using outlook 2007 with exchange 2010

```
 var deleteItem = folderItems[i];
 deleteItem.Delete(2); // Flag = HardDelete
```

The exact same line works with outlook 2010, is this a known issue or maybe there's something wrong?

PS: I'm deleting the mail straight from the ost file, exchange connection mode = olOnline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dfHardDelete is Exchange specific that only works in the online mode. Why not use the default dfSoftDelete (0)?

Comment: If I use softDelete flag and there's a retention policy on the exchange server, what's going to happen with the mail? Is it going in Deleted Items?

Comment: If you use dfSoftDelete, the message will be deleted but may still be recoverable for an Exchange store. If your wan to move the message to the Deleted Items folder, use the dfMoveToDeletedItems flag (=1).